# Nesting list lookup in a loop in Python

Tags: python, list

This must be very basic but how can we do

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 2, 0]
for k in range(1, 4):
    for i in range(0, len(a)+1-k):
        myList[a[i]][a[i+1]][a[i+2]]...[a[i+k]] += 1
```

in Python (without the `...` of course)?

Comment: do you need to add 1 to every item in list

Comment: can  provide what output you ant to achieve or your code should do , also what is  `myList`, nested list or dict ?

Comment: well if mylist is dictnoary or nested list and if the a[b[1]] value exist in mylist and for a[b[1]] value at index or key [b[2]] exist , ie as long as this exist you can do this over all as long as key/index exist you can process this

Comment: it depend on the depth of `myList`, you can consider `mylist` as tree and `mylist[a[0]]` as child of the node element and `mylist[a[0]][a[1]]` as child of `mylist[a[0]]` node, so as long as a child element exist and tree has constant depth/height then for a[i+k] we got index error in mylist then we cannpt use that k value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do the job:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 2, 0]
for k in range(1, 4):
    for i in range(0, len(a)+1-k):
        j = myList[a[i]]
        for z in range(i+1,i+k):
            j = j[a[z]]
        j[a[i+k]] += 1
```

In Python, `=` acts as a binding operator for mutable entities. It will create a reference to what you have tried to access here and increment the value as required.

Think of it like this:

> Initially, `j = myList[a[i]]`.
>   Then in the first iteration of the loop
>   involving `z`, `j = j[a[i+1]]` i. e. It will create a reference to
>   `myList[a[i]][a[i+1]]` and store it in `j`.
>   This will repeat until the
>   desired reference is achieved.

Edit: If the `z` loop is inclusive of the index `i+k`, the last value will be immutable, which wouldn't work as a reference. Hence, made it exclusive of `i+k` and later incremented the value at `i+k` in `j`.

Answer (score 2):

Param Siddarath answer is straight forward, but what if **`KeyError`** or **`NonSubscriptable Error`**, not present it will break all. just need to handle that. For key error you can ignore, that ***sublist*** but if ***non subscriptable*** you add plus 1 there

```py
a = [0, 1, 2, 2, 0]
for k in range(1, 4):
    for i in range(0, len(a)+1-k):
        try :
            j = myList[a[i]]
            for z in range(i+1,i+k):
                j = j[a[z]]
            j[a[i+k]] += 1
        except KeyError:
            continue
        except Exception
            j[a[z]] += 1
```

Comment: Whether or not that error takes place completely depends on `myList`. However, the last line `j[a[z]] += 1` is outside the `for` loop involving `z` and hence will not work. I think the error handling you intend to do must be inside the `z` loop.

Comment: in python if  you are out of loop, in between the variable is declare there it self you can access it below, means outside loop. For example I am breaking loop on x equals 5, x value is retain
```python
>>> for x in range(1, 10):
...        if x == 5: break
...
>>> x
5
```

I have not tried this in try, except block, but thinks still z will retains its value where its out of loop

Comment: We certainly can, but my point is, if we wish to avoid having a `KeyError`, we must check for the existence of a key for every value of `z`, so it would be better to handle it inside the loop.